# How to get Token from Django Rest Framework using postman

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework, postman

I try to get Token like in Django Rest Framework Documentation

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
]
```

inside models.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

But it always return to me

```
  {
  "username": [
    "This field is required."
  ],
  "password": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}
```

[image: Postman window]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add the informations in body request (choice this option).
for example:

{"username": "Werton",
 "password": "xpto"}

[image]

Comment: Also make sure to select media type "JSON"

Comment: Thanks. For anyone who still isn't clear, you need to insert the username and password parameters in the 'Body' tab of Postman, not the 'Query' tab that is selects as default.